# Adding delimiters to CSV column

Tags: macos, csv, awk

I need help writing a script that will add `:` between two characters in a single column csv file. Based on my research awk looks like the tool I need but I am stuck trying to merge two solutions and I am looking for help.

My csv column involves MAC addresses without delimiters

```
000000000000
111111111111
222222222222
```

I need the output to convert to

```
00:00:00:00:00:00
11:11:11:11:11:11
22:22:22:22:22:22
```

and I have about 1500 of these in a csv file i would like to convert.

I found a solution to add the `:` for every two characters:

```
add=000000000000
echo $add | awk '{for(i=1;i<=length($0);i+=2){printf("%s:",substr($0,i,2))}}'|awk '{sub(/:$/,"")};1' 
00:00:00:00:00:00
```

I also found an example that will read from column 1:

```
awk -F "\"*,\"*" '{print $1}' myfile.csv
```

However, I need help reading each row in the column, applying the script to add the `:` and then write the file to column 2 or a whole new file it doesn't matter to me.

Comment: An additional point: Although the solutions posted so far work for the test cases, actual MAC addresses are hexadecimal, so anywhere the examples show `[0-9]` (in sed, awk or perl) they will need to be `[0-9a-fA-F]`.

Answer (score 3):

POSIX Awk:

```
{
  for (x = 1; x < length; x += 2) {
    printf "%s%s", substr($0, x, 2), x == length - 1 ? RS : ":"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

### GNU sed

```
sed  -e 's/\([0-9][0-9]\)/\1:/g' -e 's/:$//' file
```

input:

```
000000000000
111111111111
222222222222
```

output:

```
00:00:00:00:00:00
11:11:11:11:11:11
22:22:22:22:22:22
```

Comment: I am using MAC OSX and could not get this to work, I kept getting an error

Comment: @svt1998gt: it's GNU sed, there are some differences with the BSD one. Try to google the differences, i think the -E, \w or label could be a problem.

Comment: I tried sed  ':k;s/\([0-9][0-9]\)\([0-9][0-9]\)/\1:\2/;tk' input.csv > output.csv It seems as if this copied without changes. Keep in mind that there is a <cr> after all fields. not a space in between.

Comment: @svt1998gt label also removed: command line is now much better :)

Comment: Endoro- I gave this a shot and it seems as if the file was pasted over without changes. here is my command - sed  's/\([0-9][0-9]\)\B/\1:/g' in.csv > out.csv

Comment: @svt1998gt    Escape of parantheses is missing in your line, try this: `sed 's/\([0-9][0-9]\)\B/\1:/g' file`

Comment: Hi i tried this but it seems as if this replaced ever 4th "B" with : in my file.

Comment: Here is the output -00:00:0000:00:00
11:11:1111:11:11
222:2222:22:22:2
33:33:3333:33:33
444444444444

Comment: @svt1998gt this also does work here: `sed 's/\(..\)/\1:/g;s/:$//' file`.

Comment: Hi, I was able to re-edit the file for some reason excel on macbook wasnt saving the file correct. I have the output but there is a : at the end of each entry.

Comment: @svt1998gt Your excel leaves trailing spaces or `tabs`, try it with POSIX: `sed 's/\([0-9][0-9]\)/\1:/g;s/:[[:space:]]*$//' file` (works here).

Comment: @svt1998gt (et. al) the reason this doesn't work on mac sed is that it doesn't recognize `;` as a command separator. You need to either have a literal newline or two `-e` statements

Answer (score 1):

You might give a try to

```
awk '{print gensub("([0-9][0-9])([0-9][0-9])([0-9][0-9])([0-9][0-9])([0-9][0-9])([0-9][0-9‌​])","\\1:\\2:\\3:\\4:\\5","g")}' INPUTFILE
```

Comment: @Kevin is correct, I think. A solution could be `awk '{gensub("([0-9][0-9])([0-9][0-9])([0-9][0-9])([0-9][0-9])([0-9][0-9])([0-9][0-9])","\\1:\\2:\\3:\\4:\\5","g");print}' INPUTFILE`, if you're using gawk, because `gensub()` has numbered match replacements whereas `gsub()` does not. See the [gawk manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html)

Comment: @Simon you are right, thanks for correcting me! And Kevin, your answer almost works, except that `gensub` does not replaces in place, so you need to `print` the return value of `gensub`.

Answer (score 0):

Perl will also do and changes the file inplace which awk does not do:

```
perl -pi -e 's/(..)/$1:/g;s/:$//g' your_file
```

Tested:

```
> cat temp
000000000000
111111111111
222222222222
> perl -pe 's/(..)/$1:/g;s/:$//g' temp
00:00:00:00:00:00
11:11:11:11:11:11
22:22:22:22:22:22
>
```

If you insist on awk :

```
awk '{gsub("..","&:");print substr($0,0,length($0)-1)}' your_file
```

Comment: I tried using perl, and the output put a : at the end of the last 0, here is an example of the output - 00:00:00:00:00:00:
1:11:11:11:11:11:1
:

Comment: It seems your values have spaces at the end of the line.present a proper input that you are working on. How does your file look?

Comment: My apologies Vijay, the intial question has been updated. There are no spaced but a line break.

Comment: I tested the same input and its working for me as you can see in my answer. what is the output that you get?

Comment: I was able to edit the csv file again, and the perl statement posts a : at the end of each line.

Answer (score 0):

Another way with `sed`:

```
sed 's/../:&/2g' file
```

```
$ cat file
000000000000
111111111111
222222222222
$ sed 's/../:&/2g' file
00:00:00:00:00:00
11:11:11:11:11:11
22:22:22:22:22:22
```